# Chef Tutorial fails on configure MySQL for lamp cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, devops, cookbook

I'm trying to follow the Chef tutorial (ref. https://learn.chef.io/modules/create-a-web-app-cookbook/ubuntu/virtualbox/configure-mysql#/), to build a LAMP cookbook.

I've, as tutorial suggest, my chef dk on windows and my final node is Ubuntu 14.04 hosted on Oracle Virutalbox via vagrant.

When I try to execute `kitchen converge` I obtain

```
  Missing Cookbooks:
  ------------------
  No such cookbook: seven_zip

  Expanded Run List:
  ------------------
  * lamp::default
```

My `metadata.rb` file is the follow

```
name 'lamp'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'All Rights Reserved'
description 'Installs/Configures lamp'
long_description 'Installs/Configures lamp'
version '0.1.0'
chef_version '>= 12.14' if respond_to?(:chef_version)

issues_url 'https://github.com/learn-chef/lamp/issues' if respond_to?(:issues_url)
source_url 'https://github.com/learn-chef/lamp' if respond_to?(:source_url)
supports 'ubuntu'

depends 'httpd', '~> 0.6'
depends 'mysql', '~> 8.5'
depends 'mysql2_chef_gem', '~> 2.1'
depends 'database', '~> 6.1'
```

and the lamp cookbook `default.rb` recipe is the follow

```
apt_update 'daily' do
  frequency 86_400
  action :periodic
end

include_recipe 'lamp::web'
include_recipe 'lamp::database'
```

My `kitchen.yml` is the follow ....

```
---
driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
    - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.34.34"}]

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero
  always_update_cookbooks: true

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu-14.04

suites:
  - name: default
    data_bags_path: test/fixtures/default/data_bags
    run_list:
      - recipe[lamp::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    attributes:
```

Details for chef ....

```
Chef Development Kit Version: 3.1.0
chef-client version: 14.2.0
delivery version: master (6862f27aba89109a9630f0b6c6798efec56b4efe)
berks version: 7.0.4
kitchen version: 1.22.0
inspec version: 2.1.72
```

What about seven zip if my node use Ubuntu? Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you see a `Berksfile` in the same folder as the `metadata.rb`? It should have been created automatically by `chef generate cookbook`.

Comment: Yes I've it:  Its content is ... `source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
metadata` ... .... (and also a `Berkfile.lock` file ....)

Comment: Sounds correct, look in your Berksfile.lock, do you see `seven_zip`?

Comment: Yes I see it. My problem is that I've follow the tutorial and I don't know how modify my cookbook to include seven zip too.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Try deleting and re-creating your Test Kitchen instance? You can also try deleting `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks` and running `berks update` again.

Comment: Do you mean kitchen destroy? I've just tried it but does not solve ... What command do you mean??

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I've tried to eliminate my kitchen instance with `kitchen destroy` and then I used again `kitchen create` and `kitchen converge`.  The error now is the follow `Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/seven_zip/providers/archive.rb    ....... NameError uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000000004c56030>::Windows` Different error but always about `seven_zip` package ...

Comment: Okay, so that's an improvement. What version of Chef do you see running in the start of the Test Kitchen output?

Comment: The output is the following .... `Starting Chef Client, version 14.3.37` and also, if are useful ... `Starting Kitchen (v1.22.0)`   and  `Resolving cookbook dependencies with Berkshelf 7.0.4...`

Comment: Okay, do you also see the `windows` cookbook being loaded, both in the `Berksfile.lock` and the chef-client output?

Comment: Yes! And in my  `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks` I've `windows-5.0.0` and in `Berksfile.lock` I've  `windows (>= 0.0.0)`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full output from Test Kitchen, and update any other examples where what you have has changed.

Comment: I've open a new question with all the data I've: I think is more clear in this way ..... here you're the link .... I appreciate if you coud reply there .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949833/chef-tutorial-fails-on-configure-mysql. Thank a lot!